# How to fix Slider Pro bug?

Tags: jquery, css

Please help me fix the bug in the slider (or spoiler) ..

In general, the slider itself works fine, but when I hide it in the spoiler - when it is deployed, it is skewed, but the browser window is worth a little resize - the slider is aligned - what could be the problem? (

Perhaps the problem is not in the slider, but in the spoiler?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#example3').sliderPro({
    width: 960,
    height: 500,
    fade: true,
    arrows: true,
    buttons: false,
    fullScreen: true,
    shuffle: true,
    smallSize: 500,
    mediumSize: 1000,
    largeSize: 3000,
    thumbnailArrows: true,
    autoplay: false
  });
});





jQuery('.spoiler > .head').on('click', function(e) {
  jQuery(this).parent('div.spoiler').children('.cont').stop().slideToggle(300).toggleClass('active');
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 20px;
}

.spoiler {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.spoiler>.head {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  background: #dcf3f8;
}

.spoiler>.cont {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.spoiler>.head:before {
  content: "\f054";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  color: #1db4c1;
  right: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.spoiler>.head.active:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bqworks.com/slider-pro/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bqworks.com/slider-pro/css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://bqworks.com/slider-pro/css/slider-pro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="spoiler">
  <div class="head">
    Open / Close spoiler
  </div>
  <div class="cont">






    <div id="example3" class="slider-pro">
      <div class="sp-slides">
        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg" />

          <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" data-horizontal="50" data-vertical="50" data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="400">
            Lorem ipsum
          </p>

          <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" data-horizontal="180" data-vertical="50" data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="600">
            dolor sit amet
          </p>

          <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" data-horizontal="315" data-vertical="50" data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="800">
            consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg" />

          <h3 class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" data-horizontal="40" data-vertical="40" data-show-transition="left">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </h3>

          <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" data-horizontal="40" data-vertical="100" data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="200">
            consectetur adipisicing elit
          </p>

          <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" data-horizontal="40" data-vertical="160" data-width="350" data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="400">
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_large.jpg" />

          <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" data-position="centerCenter" data-vertical="-50" data-show-transition="right" data-show-delay="500">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </p>

          <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" data-position="centerCenter" data-vertical="50" data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="700">
            consectetur adipisicing elit
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_large.jpg" />

          <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" data-position="bottomLeft" data-vertical="0" data-width="100%" data-show-transition="up">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_large.jpg" />

          <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" data-vertical="5%" data-horizontal="5%" data-width="90%" data-show-transition="down" data-show-delay="400">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_large.jpg" />

          <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" data-horizontal="10" data-vertical="10" data-width="300">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_large.jpg" />

          <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" data-position="bottomLeft" data-horizontal="5%" data-vertical="5%" data-width="90%" data-show-transition="up" data-show-delay="400">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_large.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_large.jpg" />

          <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" data-horizontal="50" data-vertical="50" data-show-transition="down" data-show-delay="500">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </p>

          <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" data-horizontal="50" data-vertical="100" data-show-transition="up" data-show-delay="500">
            consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sp-slide">
          <img class="sp-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif" data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_medium.jpg" data-small="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_small.jpg" data-medium="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_medium.jpg"
            data-large="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_large.jpg" data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_large.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="sp-thumbnails">
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image6_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image7_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image8_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image9_thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img class="sp-thumbnail" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image10_thumbnail.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>








  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try moving `$('#example3').sliderPro()` inside your `click` handler. It probably looks skewed because the plugin will rely on width/height calculations which won't be possible when its parent wrapper is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#example3' ).sliderPro( 'update' );
```

It solved my problem...More precisely, here's how

```
jQuery('.spoiler > .head').on('click', function(e){
  jQuery(this).parent('div.spoiler').children('.cont').stop().slideToggle(300).toggleClass('active');
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  $( '#example3' ).sliderPro( 'update' );
  e.preventDefault();
});
```